# Xamarin VS2015 ios app connect to web app api

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a iOS app that I am building in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin. I also have a Web Application with an Api, no authorisation. But when I try to connect to the api I get an error saying "Connection Refused".

I call the api through the following code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var data = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:7074/api/values/get");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config your Web API with an IP Address, say local 192.168.x.x

And replace `localhost` by that IP

```
var data = await client.GetAsync("http://191.268.x.x:7074/api/values/get");
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It took me a while to gain access to the VM I am working from but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` will point to your iOS device/emulator, not the server.  You need to specify the IP or FQDN in the url.  Also be be sure the firewall is open and that IIS is setup to accept remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is your iPhone / iPad or simulator (the device where you run your app). You have to change it to the IP/Domain of your server.

If the server is your dev machine, ensure, that your phone is connected to the same network (e.g. via WiFi), else you might have the same problem, because your dev machine might not be reachable.

You can find the IP of your dev machine by typing `ipconfig | find "IPv4"` into the console (on Windows).